# Keyboard shortcuts for Mailbox App for Mac

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, dropbox, mailbox

I am using Mailbox mail client for Mac, and I'd like to know what are all the available keyboard shortcuts. Some of them are similar to Gmail (like E or R). Where can I find a complete list of shortcuts?

Answer (score 2):

In Mailbox app, when you hold the Command key, all icons in the interface are replaced by the correspondent key to be pressed as shortcut (image bellow)

[image]

Comment: This no longer seems to work, but you can decipher most of the shortcuts by poking through the menus manually.

Answer (score 0):

And if you don't like or want to modify any of those key mappings, you can do so in System Preferences.

1. Open the Keyboard system preference pane and choose the shortcut tab.
2. Select **App Shortcuts** from the left then click the plus sign just below the right display box
3. Click the Application drop down and choose Mail
4. Enter the menu choice you want to simplify. If the option is layered, use the `->` format like so

   `TopMenu->NextMenu->Option`
5. Enter a shortcut key combination in the 3rd box and hit OK

This shortcut will only be available when this application is running and is the active window. But be careful to not use existing key combos (like <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>). Hopes this helps